# chrome.windows.getAll() wait iterate and sendResponse

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

When user click on button this will send a message

```js
// content script
    document.querySelector('#library').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "check if print"}, (response) => {
            console.log(response)
        });
        
    })
```

```js
// background
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        chrome.windows.getAll({}, function (windows_list) {
            windows_list.forEach(function (window) {
                if (window.type === "popup") {
// push array or sendResponse
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

I want to check if I have a popup and if I have a popUp, send a message to content script.
But on console (content) it return a error

I had tried to populate a array, when message receive on background start a array and `windows.getAll` push array, and on after this check if my array has values send a response. Of course it sendMessage before getAll finish.

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

On doc it says can use it with only queryParams and this will return a promise, but I only pass queryParams, I get error

```
// chrome documentation
getAll(queryOptions?: QueryOptions): Promise<object>
getAll(queryOptions?: QueryOptions, callback: function): void
```

```
// Error when I don't write callback
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback): No matching signature.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written

> //push array or sendResponse

sendResponse can be used only once to send-a-response.

sendMessage doc says:

> Sends a single message to event listeners within your extension/app or
> a different extension/app. Similar to runtime.connect but only sends a
> single message, with an optional response.

If you want to send only one response after chrome.windows.getAll iteration, you have to add **return true** as doc say here : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage

```
    chrome.windows.getAll({}, function (windows_list) {
        windows_list.forEach(function (window) {
            if (window.type === "popup") {
               [...]
            }
        })
        //sendResponse
        return true
    })
```

if your scenario foresee multiple popup windows, then you should think
to another way as [long-lived connections](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#connect)